# How can i add .env to codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, outlook

I try to make php connect to Outlook by follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/php-tutorial
but for environment i don't know where to put it or create new file.
Please help and explain to me?

```
OAUTH_APP_ID=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD=YOUR_APP_PASSWORD_HERE
OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:8000/authorize
OAUTH_SCOPES='openid profile offline_access User.Read Mail.Read'
OAUTH_AUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: That tutorial is using Laravel, so you need to translate the code to fit Codeigniter. Instead of using .env, put the settings in your config-file and just modify the code to get the config in the correct way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a showcase how you can implement Laravel like .env file structure in your CodeIgniter application, and make configurations easy for all the development, production, testing stages. You don't need to take care of `application/config/database.php` file each time you do `git pull` or put it in `.gitignore`.

### Steps

1. First add a package `vlucas/phpdotenv` via composer

> Run `composer require vlucas/phpdotenv` command in your project root directory. (If you don't have composer.json, don't worry, composer will take care of it.

2. Copy a file `Env.php` to your `application/libraries` directory.

> This will load your env file in environment.

3. Copy `general_helper.php` to your `application/helpers` directory.

> This will add `env` helper method to get any variable stored in `.env` file.

4. Autoload library

> Add library to `$autoload['libraries']` like this

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('env');
```

5. Autoload helper

> Add helper to `$autoload['helper']` like this

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('general');
```

6. Create an `.env` file
   Create an `.env` file in your project root folder.
7. Access an env variable

> In your php code you can access any .env variable like below

```
env('MY_VARIABLE');
```

*Source: https://github.com/technoknol/env-in-CodeIgniter*

Comment: i want to know how to use env value in config['base_url']?

Comment: Followed all of the steps, still unable to get env variable in config/database.php  file.

Comment: @rahim.nagori I had the same issue, so I get rid of the Env.php file and added the code:

// Load environment variables from .env file
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(FCPATH);

/**
 * If you are using vulcas/phpdotenv >= 4.x.x then use below code, and comment above line.
 *
 * $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(FCPATH);
 */
$dotenv->load();

in the beginning of the /application/config/config.php and worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a new file named .env, and put it on you web root.
Then, install package `vlucas/phpdotenv` use composer .
This package can Loads environment variables from .env to getenv(), $_ENV and $_SERVER automagically.
The Laravel framework distinguish environment by it.