# PHP codeigniter unable to load env variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've application structure as follows

```
> myproj   
>   -- application
>     -- config
>       -- config.php  
>   ...   
>   .env
>   index.php
```

.env file contains below

```
SERVER_PORT=8000
HTTP_HOST=localhost
```

I'm running `php index.php serve` following codeigniter documentation. I'm getting error

```
 Undefined index: SERVER_PORT in /Users/shwetanka/projects/myproj/application/config/config.php on line 26

$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
```

Above is the line where I'm getting the error. I'm new to PHP and CodeIgniter. What am I missing as document says .env file will be automatically detected and should be at root level. How do I run an existing application?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852926/how-can-i-add-env-to-codeigniter

Comment: @Vickel link is for codeigniter 3